# Calling the new expression in an overload of operator new

Tags: c++, new-operator

Is the following code undefined behavior according to the C++ standard? Please share C++ standard references.

```
void* operator new(std::size_t sz)
{
    return ::new int(5);
}
```

Comment: Follow these links [(1) Stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviours-that-a-c-programmer-should-know-a) and [(2) cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). I hope this helps! Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**6.7.5.4.1**<sup>1</sup> specifically talks about the requirements on allocation functions. It lays out all the requirements that such a function must meet, and doesn't explicitly forbid calling the global allocation function.

It does say this:

> If it is successful, it returns the address of the start of a block of storage whose length in bytes is at least as large as the requested size.

Your function always returns a block of size equal to `sizeof(int)`.

**6.7.5.4** Also says this

> If the behavior of an allocation or deallocation function does not satisfy the semantic constraints specified in [basic.stc.dynamic.allocation] and [basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation], the behavior is undefined.

The previous version of this answer missed that point. Your function doesn't return a memory block that is equal in size to the requested size (which is ignored), so the behavior is undefined.

---

<sup>1</sup> On [this](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.dynamic#allocation) site.

Comment: @Chipster I did that, but then realized I was completely wrong. I fixed that, mentioned the resource used and added quotes

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Much better. +1.